# Visual Basic Excel Regular Expression {}

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have some trouble with {}. When i get max value like this {1,8} it not work and i don't now why. Min vale is valid well

```
Private Sub Highlvl_Expression()
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,8}"
Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = ""
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim Test As Boolean
With regEx
     .Global = True
     .MultiLine = True
     .IgnoreCase = False
     .Pattern = strPattern
End With
Test = regEx.Test(Highlvl.Value)
If regEx.Test(Highlvl.Value) Then
    MsgBox ("Validate")
Else
    MsgBox ("Not Validate")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: use anchors `Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,8}$"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified the pattern that looks for 1 to 8 alphanumeric characters inside a string. If you run the regex against a 9-character string `"ABCDE6789"` (`regEx.Execute("ABCDE6789")`), you will have 2 matches: `ABCDE678` and `9`.

If you want to validate a string that should have a minimum or a maximum number of characters, you need to use [*anchors*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), i.e. start and end of string assertions [`^`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#caret) and [`$`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#dollar). So, use

```
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,8}$"
```

And

```
.Global = False
```

The global flag is not necessary since we are not looking for multiple matches, but for a single true or false result with `test`.